# $5(a^2+b^2)$ covers all numbers $=a_2^2+a_2^2=b_1^2+b_2^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I start by noting that 4a*2b=2a*4b

I write 4a*2b as $((2a+b)+(2a-b))*((2a+b)-(2a-b))  = (2a+b)^2-(2a-b)^2$
I follow a similar principle for 2a*4b which I write as $(a+2b)^2-(a-2b)^2$
to arrive at

$(2a+b)^2-(2a-b)^2= (a+2b)^2-(a-2b)^2$ or

$(2a+b)^2+(a-2b)^2= (a+2b)^2+(2a-b)^2=5(a^2+b^2)$
 The expression $5(a^2+b^2)$ thus gives numbers which can be represented as a sum of two squares in two different ways, and I observe that if a=b, a=2b (or b=2a) we have simpler relations such as (a,b)=(1,1) which gives us $5*2=3^ 2+1 $

I observe that we cover $50=7^2+1^2=5^5+5^5$, $65=8^2+1^1=7^2+4^2$ etc.

I now wonder does this simple formula cover all such numbers?

This doesn’t necessarily follow from my simple calculation.

Comment: A counterexample (maybe the smallest) is $13*17 = 221 = 10^2+11^2 = 14^2+ 5^2$.

Comment: On the whole, number of representations as the number of two squares goes up most quickly with the number of ***distinct*** prime factors that are each $1 \pmod 4.$ However, you could have included, for instance, $25 = 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2 + 0^2$

Comment: For **exactly** 2 ways -- http://oeis.org/A025303

Comment: This may be of interest in  another question I am looking at now - regarding the number of primes < n by looking at sums of 2 squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 13 (a^2 + b^2) = (3a+2b)^2 + (2a-3b)^2 =  (3a-2b)^2 + (2a+3b)^2$$
$$ 17 (a^2 + b^2) = (4a+b)^2 + (a-4b)^2 =  (4a-b)^2 + (a+4b)^2$$
$$ 29 (a^2 + b^2) = (5a+2b)^2 + (2a-5b)^2 =  (5a-2b)^2 + (2a+5b)^2$$
$$ 37 (a^2 + b^2) = (6a+b)^2 + (a-6b)^2 =  (6a-b)^2 + (a+6b)^2$$
$$ 41 (a^2 + b^2) = (5a+4b)^2 + (4a-5b)^2 =  (5a-4b)^2 + (4a+5b)^2$$